# UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "tel://\(varContact)")!) asking for Call/Cancel?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using below code for calling directly in viewdidload

```
 if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "tel://\(varContact)")!)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "tel://\(varContact)")!)
    }
```

while executing it pop up for call/cancel ....I don't want user interaction for calling ? what to do ?

Comment: you cannot do anything. :P

Comment: call popup comes from os. so, you can not be ignored. even you will check contact number from email and website and when you tap on number same popup will show you.

Comment: Apple will not allow you to do this.